# Multiple values for one column field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

How do i create a column which stores multiple values for a `User` model in Rails app?

Example:

I want to have a `User` model and store multiple fruit preferences. What type of `fruit_preference` would i need to add in order to store multiple `fruit_preference` values? Such as: `fruit_preference: apple, orange, pear`

I want to find specific users based on one of those fruits in my app later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the original question - [array data type](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array).

But what you really need is [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

```
class User
 has_many :fruits
end

class Fruit
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Having such setup you will be able to query users to find those with specific fruit:

```
User.joins(:fruits).where(fruits: {name: 'apple'})
```

As well, as having all user's fruits (because he can have multiple):

```
User.first.fruits
#=> collection of Fruit objects
```

This is way better, that storing user's fruits as a collection in database, because pretty quick maintaining/changing/updating these collections becomes hard.

Comment: I was aware of associations but didn't know you could utilize them this way. That's exactly what i've been looking for. Thanks.